# DNS для Docker (Service discovery)

Tags: docker, dns

Как и чем реализовать dns с автоматическим обнаружением контейнеров, внутри которых лежат по несколько сайтов?
т.е. 
1. Создается контейнер с Nginx, в нем 3 сайта 
2. Регистратор получает информацию о новом контейнере
3. Добавляет/удаляет/изменяет данные в DNS

Comment: *1. создаётся* — кем?

Comment: *как и чем?* — да чем угодно. на любом удобном вам языке программирования пишете реализацию отдельных подзадач. но для начала, конечно, ваш очень глобальный вопрос надо разбить на множество мелких (частично, скорее всего нерешаемых в той **общей** формулировке, что вы привели) подзадач.

Comment: Контейнер создается вручную или средствами скрипта. 
Не знаете ли вы подобных тем, от чего можно оттолкнуться, не знаю с чего начать даже.

Comment: разбейте на мелкие подзадачи — и сразу станет понятнее, что вообще нереализуемо, и как реализовывать то, что реализовать таки можно.

Comment: а, главное: уберите из списка этих подзадач упоминание докера. он тут лишний. от слова «совсем». т.е., эта программа ничем вам не поможет и не помешает. она лишь (в данный момент) сбивает вас с толку.

Comment: kubernetes, gliderlabs/registrator